# What does a long mid-high unrounded back vowel sound like?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa

I'm trying to figure out what the Livonian character ȱ sounds like. As far as I can tell, it's a long mid-high unrounded back vowel. In IPA it seems to be written as `/ɤː/` but that seems to be a non-standard IPA form?

Answer (score 4):

The symbol [ɤː] is the correct one for the sound you describe and is a standard IPA symbol (although it's not a super-common vowel in the world's languages, but does crop up here and there).

There is also the *near-high* (as opposed to *high-mid*) back rounded vowel [ʊ]; perhaps this is what you were expecting?

As for what these sound like, have a look at this website: http://www.ipachart.com/.

Comment: I don't find that source reliable as it uses crowdsourced sounds. I recommend [this](http://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/keating/IPA/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html) and [this](https://www.seeingspeech.ac.uk/ipa-charts/), which are made by top phoneticians.

Comment: Thanks for adding these! Seeing Speech is especially good.

Comment: Although the [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livonian_language#Phonology) says *ȯ* in Livonian represents [ʊ], the [Latvian article](https://lv.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C4%ABbie%C5%A1u_valoda#Patska%C5%86i), which is substantiated with more sources, says it's either [ɤ] or [ɤ̞].

Comment: I was under the impression that [ʊ] is near-back by default; is that not the case?

Comment: That is indeed what it is called on page 170 of the Handbook of the IPA; I was just trying simplify things a little (and in any case it does also get used for back as well as near-back near-high rounded vowels).